# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object when i get data

Tags: laravel

i get this error when i get section data and the **problem with section result part**
the book part and author part working good 
when i remove section part it working with out section_name
Laravel Framework version 5.1.25 (LTS)

> ```
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\resources\views\libraryViewsContainer\summary.blade.php)
> ```

**my Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section','id');
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author','books_authors_relationship','book_id','author_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**my BooksController**

```
public function summary(){
        $all_results = Book::with('section')->with('author')->get();
        return view('libraryViewsContainer.summary',compact('all_results',$all_results));
    }
```

**my summary blade**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="well text-center">Library Summary</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 25%">Section Name</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Book Title</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Book Description</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Authors</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach($all_results as $bookModel)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/section/{{$bookModel->section->id}}">
                        <span class="label label-info">{{$bookModel->section->section_name}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$bookModel->book_title}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$bookModel->book_description}}
                    </td>
                    <?php $authors = $bookModel->author; ?>
                    <td>
                        @foreach($authors as $author)
                            <a href="/author/{{$author->id}}">
                                <span class="label label-danger">{{$author->first_name}} {{$author->last_name}}</span>
                            </a>
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: You should check empty condition for `$bookmodel->section' and if it is not then use `$bookmodel->section->section_name'

Comment: `<span class="label label-info">{{ !empty($bookModel->section)? $bookModel->section->section_name : '' }}</span>`

Comment: section_name  this field name in table section and when i put this code i get syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: relationship queries like `$bookModel->section->section_name` always return collection, you have to loop through them to get the results.

Comment: so what can i do to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was in Book model
i changed

```
public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section','id');
    }
```

to

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
```

and it worked thanks for all help me

Answer (score 0):

1. In controller, method "with" can be written like **$all_results = Book::with('section', 'author')->get();**
2. Method compact() takes the variable names, not the variables.

   return $all_results before view to see your results to get whether you're getting the values correctly or not.

Comment: i get the same error - Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: return $all_results have those values within?

Comment: this i do controller  $all_results = Book::with('section', 'author')->get();   return view('libraryViewsContainer.summary',compact('all_results',$all_results)); and view                          <a href="/section/{{$bookModel->section->id}}">
                        <span class="label label-info">{{$bookModel->section->section_name}}</span>

Comment: after this, write return $all_results; and check on browser, does that have what you're looking for?

Comment: return view('libraryViewsContainer.summary',compact('all_results',$all_results));

Comment: @fido just do, $all_results = Book::with('section', 'author')->get(); return $all_results; and check on your browser.

Comment: i get Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i'm sad the same error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: why are you returning view? just return the dataset. and for compact, check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php, @fido

Comment: $all_results = Book::with('section', 'author')->get(); return $all_results;  give me [{"id":11,"book_title":"wwwgdr","book_edition":3,"date_publication":"2015-12-15","book_isbn":"3","book_description":"vnbn ","image_name":"1.jpg","section_id":9,"created_at":"2015-12-13 17:12:58","updated_at":"2015-12-14 21:20:22","section":{"id":11,"section_name":"ww","books_total":"","image_name":"10995309_894508197272177_6911918543449012968_n.jpg","created_at":"2015-12-18

Comment: i shared the screen shot above

Comment: Laravel clearly shows the line number where it causes trying to access the property of a non object

Comment: any one have  solution